# C++ - Initialise a vector of arrays with one element

Tags: arrays, c++11, vector, initialization

In C++11, is there a nice way to initialise a vector of arrays (I mean the C++ class) with one element, like

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > foo(3, std::vector<int>(2, 1));
```

to initialise a 3x2 vector of vector with all 1s?

Unluckily, the analogue for a vector of arrays does not seem to work; am I really obliged to use a for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::array<int, 2> > v(3, {1,1});

    for(auto const& e0 : v)
    {
        for(auto const& e1 : e0)
            std::cout << e1 << ", ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1, 1, 
1, 1, 
1, 1,
```

---

"Why should we use two brackets?"

The original code in my question was

```
std::vector< std::array<int, 2> > v(3, {{1,1}});
```

but I decided to remove that second pair of braces. They've been in there to suppress a clang++ warning: Typically, `std::array` contains a (raw) array. One pair of braces is sufficient to initialize this inner array, but clang++ issues a warning because the elements of `{1,1}` (one pair of braces) are used to initialize the elements of this inner array, not the aggregate (the outer `std::array`) itself. Quoth clang++:

> warning: suggest braces around initialization of subobject

I looked this up in the Standard, and it requires in [array.overview]/2

> An array is an aggregate (8.5.1) that can be initialized with the syntax
>
> `array<T, N> a = {` *initializer-list* `};`
>
> where *initializer-list* is a comma-separated list of up to `N` elements whose types are convertible to `T`.

Argument passing uses the same specification as this form of initialization (called *copy-initialization*, [dcl.init]/15), therefore using one pair of braces is *guaranteed* to work.

OTOH, there's no requirement that `std::array` contains a (raw) array.

Comment: Your code is working splendidly, but now I have several questions:

Comment: Why should we use two brackets?

Comment: Why does not this method work if I initialise v as a global variable (outside of main)?

Comment: Since when with C++ is it possible to avoid "return 0" at the end of the main code? (I omissed it as well, and surprisingly it worked! o.O)

Comment: "Why does not this method work if I initialise v as a global variable (outside of main)?" I don't know? It works for me. Please post an example of what you did (e.g. as edit to your question).

Comment: "Since when with C++ is it possible to avoid "return 0" at the end of the main code?" It's explicitly allowed for `main` to omit the `return` statement (the effect is equivalent to `return 0;`). I don't know *when* this has been introduced, but it's legal at least since C++03 and C99.

Comment: Actually, it's a very long code. I assume that there is some problem somewhere which is unrelated to define v as global variable. ;)